Python - OpenCV - Is there a way to "Fill" an expected contour?
I want to detect the contour of a ball and the object will always be a ball, but i have an object in the middle that can obstruct part of the ball, here's my current situation :
(https://i.sstatic.net/gwxnsVTI.png)
I made it so it works just fine in this case where theres a good amount of the ball on both sides, but when it reduces its not as good:
(https://i.sstatic.net/gYiZ9bCI.png)
I know I can change the parameters of my code where I just concatenate both parts when they are of a good enough size, but it gets very situational when it works because of the noise, so I can't reduce the parameters that much:
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pyfirmata2 import Arduino, SERVO
import time
import serial



# Camera Connection/Setup
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    
    #Blue color
    low_blue = np.array([100, 100, 20])
    high_blue = np.array([200, 255, 255])
    blue_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, low_blue, high_blue)
    #blue_mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(blue_mask,(5,5),0)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(blue_mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda x:cv2.contourArea(x), reverse=True)

    sum = 0
    emptymask = []
    for cnt in contours:
        if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 300: #If the parts are big enough it assumes its a part of the ball
            sum += cv2.contourArea(cnt)
            emptymask.append(cnt)

    #print(sum)
    emptymask = cv2.vconcat(emptymask)

    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(emptymask)
   
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    cv2.imshow("Mask", blue_mask)

    
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break
        

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


So I was thinking wether I can sort of deduce the ball based on its size or something like that, since it's always the same ball.
I did do something like that in another code where if it's not the size expected, it "guesses" the whole ball and makes a square, but it became incredibly hard to calibrate the exact x and y positions:
if reference > 6000: #See if the object is cropped or not
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + w), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    elif ((x>180 and x<230) and (y>170 and y<240) or (y<5 and x<225)):                #If it is, it will calculate the rest of the area
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x+ball_diameter, y+h), (x, y+h - ball_diameter), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    elif (x>230 and x<290) and (y>140 and y<170):                #If it is, it will calculate the rest of the area
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x+w, y+ball_diameter), (x+w - ball_diameter, y), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    elif (x>270 and x<300 and (y<140 or y>230)) or (y>220 and y<250) or (y<5 and x>225):                #If it is, it will calculate the rest of the area
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x+w, y+h), (x+w - ball_diameter, y+h - ball_diameter), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    else:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + ball_diameter, y + ball_diameter), (0, 255, 0), 2)    



Finally, my question is : Is there a way to detect the arch from either side and just fill the missing circle gap ? Or an even better way ?

If you know it is a ball, then, rather than trying to find an algorithm to magically change the pixels, you would be better off trying to guess which is the more probable "ball" in the image (what triple (xcenter, ycenter, radius) maximize the adequation). For example starting from what you have (barycenter and radius of the white pixels), and using a sort of gradient descent to try to adjust the parameter to improve a metric

Please post your input image and mask image each as an original and not in combination of some other image as screen snaps.

You could clean up the small spots leaving only your two parts of the ball. Then get all white points and fit an ellipse to it or get the convex hull to close it up and fill that with white, then use HoughCircles to fit a circle to that.

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.
Since you did not post actual input files and not screen snaps, I took your image and cropped it to get the black/white mask image as my input.

Read the input mask
Convert to grayscale
Otsu threshold
Apply morphology to clean up the small spots
Get the convex hull and draw it as white filled on a black background
Get Hough Circles for the convex hull. Tune the mindist and minradius until get one circle and not null circles.
Draw Hough Circle on copy of input
Save Results
Show Results

Input:

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
img = cv2.imread('input_mask.png')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# apply morphology to clean up small spots leaving only two largest ones
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# get convex hull
points = np.column_stack(np.where(morph.transpose() > 0))
hull = cv2.convexHull(points)

# draw convex hull in white filled on black 
hull_img = np.zeros_like(morph)
cv2.fillPoly(hull_img, [hull], 255)

# get Hough circles
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(hull_img, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist=210, param1=150, param2=10, minRadius=40, maxRadius=100)
print(circles)

# draw circles
result = img.copy()
for circle in circles[0]:
    # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
    # corresponding to the center of the circle
    (x,y,r) = circle
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
    r = int(r)
    cv2.circle(result, (x, y), r, (0, 0, 255), 1)

# ALTERNATELY: get minEnclosingCircle
center, radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(hull)
cx = int(round(center[0]))
cy = int(round(center[1]))
rr = int(round(radius))

# draw minEnclosingCircle over copy of input
result2 = img.copy()
cv2.circle(result2, (cx,cy), rr, (0, 0, 255), 1)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('input_mask_morph.png', morph)
cv2.imwrite('input_mask_convex_hull.png', hull_img)
cv2.imwrite('input_mask_circle3.png', result)
cv2.imwrite('input_mask_circle3b.png', result2)

# show images
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('morph', morph)
cv2.imshow('convex hull', hull_img)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.imshow('result2', result2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Morphology cleaned image:

Convex hull image:

Resulting circle on copy of input:

Resulting circle from minEnclosingCircle on input:


This is a good idea. But instead of Hough, I would fit a circle through the points that belong to the convex hull.

@Cris Luengo There is no fitCircle, only fitEllipse. So that would have to coded in Python, would it not? Or am I missing some OpenCV method?  It would be great if someone could code up a fitCircle similar to fitEllipse in OpenCV!

I don't know if you're missing some OpenCV method. I don't know OpenCV very well. But fitting a circle to a set of points is quite simple. Much simpler than fitting an ellipse in any case!

I have modified my answer and included the alternate approach result from drawing the minEnclosingCircle in place of HoughCircle. That is the closest I can find to a fit circle although not exactly that. It will be the circle that enclosing the whole region. It is simpler in that it does not require tuning parameters.

Neat, I didn’t know that function!

Here is one more variation to what I wrote previously as an answer, which computed either the Hough circle or the min enclosing circle. In this post, I compute the least squares fit of the convex hull to a circle after reading the input, converting to grayscale, thresholding and using morphology to clean up small spots. The least squares fit to a circle is taken from scipy at https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Least_Squares_Circle.html. However, the min enclosing circle approach shown before seems to be the best (and simplest) of the 3 approaches for this example input.
Input:

import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

# Read image
img = cv2.imread('input_mask.png')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# apply morphology to clean up small spots leaving only two largest ones
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# get convex hull
points = np.column_stack(np.where(morph.transpose() > 0))
hull = cv2.convexHull(points)
x = hull[:,:,0]
y = hull[:,:,1]

# draw convex hull over copy of input 
hull_img = img.copy()
cv2.polylines(hull_img, [hull], True, (0,0,255), 1)

# compute least squares fit to circle using scipy optimize
# see https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Least_Squares_Circle.html
# == METHOD 1 ==
method_1 = 'algebraic'
# coordinates of the barycenter
x_m = np.mean(x)
y_m = np.mean(y)
# calculation of the reduced coordinates
u = x - x_m
v = y - y_m
# linear system defining the center in reduced coordinates (uc, vc):
#    Suu * uc +  Suv * vc = (Suuu + Suvv)/2
#    Suv * uc +  Svv * vc = (Suuv + Svvv)/2
Suv  = np.sum(u*v)
Suu  = np.sum(u**2)
Svv  = np.sum(v**2)
Suuv = np.sum(u**2 * v)
Suvv = np.sum(u * v**2)
Suuu = np.sum(u**3)
Svvv = np.sum(v**3)
# Solving the linear system
A = np.array([ [ Suu, Suv ], [Suv, Svv]])
B = np.array([ Suuu + Suvv, Svvv + Suuv ])/2.0
uc, vc = np.linalg.solve(A, B)
# Calculate center
xc = x_m + uc
yc = y_m + vc
# Calculate distances from the center (xc, yc) and average radius
Ri = np.sqrt((x-xc)**2 + (y-yc)**2)
R = np.mean(Ri)
residual = np.sum((Ri-R)**2)
residual2= np.sum((Ri**2-R**2)**2)
print('')
print ("center:",(xc,yc), "radius:",R, "residual:",residual)
print('')

# draw circle
result = img.copy()
xc = int(xc)
yc = int(yc)
R = int(R)
cv2.circle(result, (xc, yc), R, (0, 0, 255), 1)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('input_mask_morph.png', morph)
cv2.imwrite('input_mask_convex_hull2a.png', hull_img)
cv2.imwrite('input_mask_circle4a.png', result)

# show images
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('morph', morph)
cv2.imshow('convex hull', hull_img)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Morphology cleaned image:

Convex hull on copy of input:

Resulting least squares circle on copy of input:

